# Dark theme for Salesforce Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

StackOverflow has recently added a really awesome dark theme. I was wondering if we can ask Salesforce Stack Exchange to also add that. Thanks!

Btw for anyone who hasn't seen the Stack Overflow dark theme here's a screenshot and also note the ultra-dark theme which was added on April fool's day this year and seems it's gonna stick around, I still like the dark better than the ultra-dark, but man, the ultra-dark has some really cool features you have to try out :)

I apologize for selecting an unrelated, I wasn't sure what tag would fit this question and if you please point me to the right direction on that, I'll appreciate it and be more than happy to follow standards. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I moved this question to Meta, where questions _about_ the site can be discussed.

Comment: That's awesome, Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, it looks like from the [announcement blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/) that we are not getting dark mode on any of the Exchange sites:

> For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network. Many of the designs on our sites have been around long enough that converting them to dark mode would require redoing the artwork completely. We would prefer to avoid giving anyone across our network a substandard experience and we don’t want to change those elements without the input of these communities.

That's a real shame, but unfortunately it seems to be common for new features to come to Stack Overflow first and later, if at all, to the Exchange sites.

Comment: What about Salesforce StackExchange first and Stack Overflow second? ;)

Comment: Not sure whats the big fuss about it? I use [DarkReader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en) dark mode everywhere.